# Commit and Push keeps making new branch (Eclipse)

Tags: eclipse, egit

When using eclipse and I want to Commit / Push changes, using the Git Staging view I can hit commit, then on the Git repositories view push the branch to the remote branch. However when I hit Commit and Push it creates a new branch? The local branch is called master and the remove is origin/HEAD, and the new remote created is origin/master. The default branch is origin/HEAD. I've been Commit and Pushing to the default until today.

I've been searching for an answer for a while but I couldn't really find one, sorry if this is a duplicate.

Comment: Did Eclipse claim that the current branch is called `NO-HEAD` before you committed?

Comment: @dorukayhan It didn't. In the history it says it is `HEAD` "refs/heads/master" if that's helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It didn't [say that the current branch is `NO-HEAD`]. In the history it says it is `HEAD` "refs/heads/master" if that's helpful?

`HEAD` isn't a separate branch. It's just a pointer to the branch that is currently [checked out](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

Comment: I figured what was going on was the branch I was using was called "master" and the default branch was called "HEAD" (it was a separate branch). I ended up keeping master and changed the default branch from HEAD to master, then deleted  HEAD.